# Reformatting a JSON output with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have this JSON file that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "venue": {
      "id": "63d706ff",
      "name": "Joe Robbie Stadium",
      "city": {
        "id": "4164167",
        "name": "Miami Gardens",
        "state": "Florida",
        "stateCode": "FL",
        "coords": {
          "lat": 25.9420377,
          "long": -80.2456045
        },
        "country": {
          "code": "US",
          "name": "United States"
        }
      },
    }
  },
  {
    "venue": {
      ...
]
```

So it has venues in it with some details. Now I'd need to format the file to look like this:

```
{
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Joe Robbie Stadium",
    "country": "United States",
    "city": "Miami Gardens",
    "state": "Florida",
    "stateCode": "FL",
    "setlistfmId": "63d706ff",
  },
  "2": {
    "id": 2,
    ...
}
```

Basically it would have a running integer as the key for each venue and the details inside it. I've used `jq` in the past to do some minor formatting, but this I just can't complete. I've tried with different approaches, like building a new array/object using `map()` or just by `=` and then `del(.[].venue)` but I'm stuck and frustrated.

What should I be looking for in the [jq manual](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/)?

Don't laugh, I'm really no expert with `jq`, but to just get a couple of fields I started with e.g.:

```
cat data.json | jq '{
  testObject: {
    name: map(.venue.name),
    country: map(.venue.city.country.name)
  }
  | add
}'
```

Which does get the name of the venue and the country name, but it's all just flat like:

```
{
  "testObject": [
    "Joe Robbie Stadium",
    "Florida Suncoast Dome",
    "Spectrum",
    .....
    "United States",
    "United States",
    "United States",
  ]
}
```

Comment: One reasonable way to implement this would be as a reducer -- gives you an easy way to maintain state so you can have an incrementing counter to assign ids. Make sure your reducer is iterating over the venues themselves; you get into your problem when you iterate first over the objects _inside_ the venues directly instead of starting on the outside and iterating over the top-level objects first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `with_entries` to get the index of an object, add 1 and convert to string to use that as the index.

Then update the .value with a custom object were you get the keys you'd like, something like:

```
with_entries(.key = (.key + 1 | tostring) | .value = (.value.venue | { 
    name,
    county: .city.country.name,
    city: .city.name,
    stateCode: .city.stateCode,
    setlistfmId: .id
}))
```

Will output:

```json
{
  "1": {
    "name": "Joe Robbie Stadium",
    "county": "United States",
    "city": "Miami Gardens",
    "stateCode": "FL",
    "setlistfmId": "63d706ff"
  }
}
```

As you can play around in this [online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/k5XKKVMqK-H).

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly, thank you! I looked into with_entries at one point, but didn't realize it could be used this way. Thanks again!